# drush uses development.services.yml though not present in settings.php

Tags: drush, debugging

I am currently observing that drush seems to use development.services.yml from web/sites though development.services.yml is not added via settings.php.

Doing

```
drush php:eval "var_export(\Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('twig.config'));"
```

shows

debug => true

which seems to result from development.services.yml. If I change it in development.services.yml it changes in output too.

Twig debugging is not enabled for the site, which I can see in the source code when visiting and also if I for example try

```
var_export(\Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('twig.config'))
```

via form_alter in the backend.

Why does drush use development.services.yml when the site does not?

Comment: Maybe drupal.org/node/3359728 interfering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struggling to enable twig debugging](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316808/struggling-to-enable-twig-debugging)

Comment: I did not use the setting from drupal.org/node/3359728. And I am not struggling to enable twig debugging, but wondering why drush does somehow use development.services.yml when it is not included in the settings.

Comment: This is interesting considering that the container is not recompiled between a web and a drush request. What if you check the container parameter `\Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('site.path')`, which is used to discover the settings.php. Is this also different?

Comment: site.path gives "sites/default" via drush and via web. I have also checked in another project and it is the same there too. The problem which made me aware of this, was that indexing solr via drush was taking significantly longer than via web. This is caused by the twig debug output.

Comment: OK, then it discovers settings.php in the same site path. The next step to debug would be to check any includes in settings.php which might add development.services.yml to the container.

Comment: Yes, I will need to debug some more. The other project I mentioned is uisng development.services.yml via web too, so this was no proof. Seems something special about this one project here. But how could drush use different includes than web?

Comment: You didn't answer my last comment. Did you check the settings.php for `include` statements? The include could be conditional and the condition could depend on the way you run Drupal.

Comment: Ok yes, there is an include based on an environment variable which is set when calling via drush but not when calling via web (different user probably). Thanks for your help.